# Add controls to contextual menu in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu

I would like to add some contextual menu to some controls a in WPF project. This in itself is easy enough. I was wondering if it was possible to have controls like textbox or datepicker in them, much like Access have when click a on cell in a table, where you can filter by a textbox value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put whatever you like inside a `ContextMenu`, not only `MenuItems`. I never thought about it but I guess you could use it as a `Popup` when someone right click it. You can also add events etc.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="myContextMenu">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="Some Text.."/>
                <DatePicker/>
                <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Text="Display some controls on right click"
             ContextMenu="{StaticResource myContextMenu}"/>
    <TextBox Text="Display some controls on right click"
             ContextMenu="{StaticResource myContextMenu}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

*Get the clicked `UIElement` in the event handler*

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    StackPanel stackPanel = button.Parent as StackPanel;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = stackPanel.Parent as ContextMenu;
    UIElement elementWithMenu = contextMenu.PlacementTarget;
}
```

Comment: I imagine I can define the event like any other control. If I want the exact same menu on many controls, can I use a style and I would get the source with the eventArgs ?

Comment: Yes, you can share this `ContextMenu` on many controls, and you can also add events and find the control it was clicked on